# Windows 8 Databound App Tutorial

Tags: sql, database, windows-8

Does anybody know of a good tutorial, preferably with downloadable sample code, for a Windows 8 app that is data oriented?

I am trying to rewrite a fairly simple Windows Forms application, which uses a local SQL Express database, as a Modern UI Windows 8 app, but it seems that Windows 8 apps don't support accessing SQL databases natively.  This leaves me wondering what the best way to store the app's data is, and also lost as to how to handle calls to create/edit/delete records, etc.

I've come across the [Reversi](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj712233.aspx#databinding) sample app, which Microsoft claims contains extensive examples of databinding, but actually it all seems to be in an MVVM context, binding visibility of controls, positions of items, etc.  I'd like to see an example of a more traditional, simple database application with records that can be browsed, updated, created, deleted, etc.  Not least so that I can just see how the data is stored, since an external database apparently isn't an option!

Answer (score 1):

You can use SQLite as database for Windows Store App. There are couple of articles & code sample available.

[SQLite samples from MSDN](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/site/search?query=sqlite&f%5B0%5D.Value=sqlite&f%5B0%5D.Type=SearchText&ac=4)

[Using SQLite in Windows 8 Store Apps](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/robertgreen/archive/2012/11/13/using-sqlite-in-windows-store-apps.aspx)

[WinRT app guide: Step 10: Adding a lightweight database (SQLite) and CRUD support + two-way element binding](http://www.irisclasson.com/2012/10/02/winrt-app-guide-step-10-adding-a-lightweight-database-sqlite-and-crud-support-two-way-element-binding/)